# keyof type operator with indexed signature

Tags: typescript

I was reading through typescript [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html#the-keyof-type-operator) and came through this code excerpt:

```
type Mapish = { [k: string]: boolean };
type M = keyof Mapish;
```

and they gave the following explanation:

> Note that in this example, M is string | number — this is because JavaScript object keys are always coerced to a string, so obj[0] is always the same as obj["0"].

so my question is why `number` exclusively? why not `boolean` or `object`?

Comment: Because booleans and objects don't make sense object keys: they don't give unique values when coerced to strings. Only Symbols, Strings, and Numbers make sense as object keys, trying to do so with other types is basically always a programmer mistake. Contrast with a Map which can have arbitrary keys.

Comment: But you can use both of them as kyes of a `Map`.

Comment: Yes, as I said a Map can have arbitrary keys, that's the entire reason they added it in ES6. But trying to use any object that doesn't have a custom `toString` method as a key for another object yields up "[object Object]" which again is basically always a mistake in the code.

Comment: When I said "only Symbols, Strings, and Numbers make sense as object keys" above it's because of the coercion you mention in your question: unlike the keys in a Map, *object* keys are coerced to strings.

Comment: Numeric index signatures are there to support arrays and array-like objects.  People don't normally try to index into JS objects with booleans or objects, so TS doesn't model such indexing.  But people index into arrays with numbers all the time, and it would be really annoying if TS didn't allow numbers to be seen as object keys.  Does that address your question or am I missing something?  If it addresses it I can write up an answer.

Comment: @JaredSmith nitpick: `true` and `false` would indeed produce unique values when coerced to strings, but using booleans as keys in JS is vanishingly rare, so TS has no reason to model it.  Numbers on the other hand are used all the time as indices.

Comment: @jcalz does this imply that you can only use `number` and `string` as types in index signature?

Comment: You can also use `symbol` and pattern template literals like `\`foo${string}\``.  But you can't use `boolean` or `object`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TypeScript supports `string` and `number` [index signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures), and (starting with TypeScript 4.4) [`symbol` and pattern template literal index signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-4.html#symbol-and-template-string-pattern-index-signatures).  Objects in JavaScript only really have `string` and `symbol` keys, so the `string`, `symbol`, and pattern template literal (which are a subtype of `string`) index signatures in TypeScript should make perfect sense.  But what's with `number`?

---

Numeric index signatures  are specifically intended to support [arrays](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#the-array-type) and other arraylike objects.  It would be very annoying if indexing into an array with a numeric index produced a TypeScript error:

```
const arr = ["a", "b", "c"];
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  console.log(arr[i].toUpperCase());
  // -----------> ~ <-- error, you can't index with a number? 
}
```

Requiring non-idiomatic JavaScript like `arr[String(i)]` would be inconvenient.  And it wouldn't even help; the compiler can't really tell the difference between `String(1)` and any other string, so it wouldn't understand that `arr[String(1)]` should be an element of the array, as opposed to a method like `arr["pop"]`.

So even though objects don't really have `number`-valued keys, TypeScript *pretends* that they do in order to support arrays more naturally, because arrays are very commonly used with numeric indices in idiomatic JavaScript code.

---

On the other hand, nobody indexes into JavaScript objects with other objects, or with `boolean` keys:

```
// nobody does this
const foo = { true: 1, false: 0, "[object Object]": 2 };
console.log(foo[Math.random() < 0.5]) // what
console.log(foo[{ a: 123 }]); // what are you doing
```

Well, maybe not *nobody*, but it is so rare that code like `foo[false]` or `foo[{}]` is much more likely to be a programming mistake than intended code.  So TypeScript has no reason to allow `boolean` or `object` index signatures.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgJwTAvDA2gIjpgNDTAIzwOEwF0BuAWACgAzEZACgBsBTWAS1RgAZKMHgB54SAHQcwAcygALQVwDUSgJQwA3nRgxQkEB0khpzRAnRdy4qCACqAB3vsEAYTgR2zVapq0dAen8YAFpQsPDggD4YAD8YYVCYZwQmfABPEABXXTgwAHJuMAATdgAPGAB3Lnl4GDBMgFtCZxg6AF86OkC6kEIQIrSYIpB2CBh5Lgg6PWgYRhBeDXGETPYALhgARnx6OFYPDb58THRegCt2YFgAeUILq-JMDYAmGDbfGYN2IxN59ABZODycQIXLDBpeeL8cQAVnIqmm4AgXx+zD+SzgG02zwAzG94b46EA)