# The weird types of TypeScript's keyof for objects

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typeof

I am struggling to understand TypeScript's types when using the `keyof` type operator on objects.
Have a look at [the following example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKuEEEoF4oG8oG0DWAuKAdgK4C2ARhAE4C6%20ZA9vQDYQCGBUAvgNwBQokKAgDSEECijYx9AGax4CPgHolUNQD0A-L37x5kAEISMOfAGdglAJYEA5rSgNmbDj12CDo8aikhZ%20iANlVQ1td2g4SABhYyxsKBtCUgoaOkYWdi4%20AWgorwlff0iIKOC1KC0dHICAEVicBI4LazsHJwzXbL0a-J9pOWKastDeIA):

```js
type TypeA = { [k: number]: boolean };
type AKey = keyof TypeA;
//   ^? type AKey = number

type TypeB = { [k: string]: boolean };
type BKey = keyof TypeB;
//   ^? type BKey = string | number
```

The [TypeScript documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html) contains a note saying something like:

> Note that in this example, `keyof { [k: string]: boolean }` is `string | number` — this is because JavaScript object keys are always coerced to a string, so obj[0] is always the same as obj["0"].

That make it seems as if it should be the exact opposite.
That `AKey` should be number (because they are always coerced to a string), and `BKey` should just be a string, because the type doesn't allow numbers.

And if that isn't confusing enough, the same doesn't hold true when using `Record<>`.
That seems to be because the definition uses `in` instead of `:`:

```js
type Record<K extends string | number | symbol, T> = { [P in K]: T; }

type TypeC = { [k in number]: boolean }; // Record<number, boolean>
type CKey = keyof TypeC;
//   ^? type CKey = number

type TypeD = { [k in string]: boolean }; // Record<string, boolean>
type DKey = keyof TypeD;
//   ^? type DKey = string
```

All types do allow using both numbers and strings as keys, so the type definitions don't seem to affect that in any way:

```js
const value: TypeA | TypeB | TypeC | TypeD = {
  0: false,
  "1": true,
};
```

Can anyone help me understand this type circus?

Comment: The index signature with number index is designed for Array-like types, when you want the users of the type to index by position. In fact, Array definition itself uses such index signature. Note that for convenience, string literals corresponding to numbers can be used. On the other hand index signature with string index is designed for Dictionary-like types - unknown keys corresponding to a values of a given type. I rarely, if ever, use the convenience of indexing by number in such cases.

Comment: It is explained (or at least specified) in [ms/TS#23592](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/23592). Mapped types behave differently from index signatures intentionally, although the "why" of that isn't something I can speculate about beyond pointing to that PR.  Your "exact opposite" intuition is wrong because every "`number`" key is also a `string` key, but not vice versa.  So it's safe to consider `number` a valid key type for something with a `string` index signature, but not vice versa.  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer; if not, what's missing?

Comment: @jcalz Ah, you are completely right about my intuition! Makes sense now. Yes, please write a "real" answer :)

Comment: I will do so when I get a chance. Might be a few hours from now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior of [the `keyof` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html#the-keyof-type-operator) when applied to [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) and to types with [index signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) is specified in the implementing pull request at [microsoft/TypeScript#23592](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/23592).  The rules are:

> Given an object type `X`, `keyof X` is resolved as follows:
>
> - If `X` contains a string index signature, `keyof X` is a union of `string`, `number`, and the literal types representing symbol-like properties, otherwise
> - If `X` contains a numeric index signature, `keyof X` is a union of `number` and the literal types representing string-like and symbol-like properties, otherwise
> - `keyof X` is a union of the literal types representing string-like, number-like, and symbol-like properties.

TypeScript treats numeric keys of type `number` a subtype of keys of type `string` (this is a convenient fiction to support array indexing; object keys are never really `number`, but instead numeric *strings*.  But I digress, see [keyof type operator with indexed signature](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72331093/2887218) for more).  That means every numeric key is really a string key, but not every string key is a numeric key.  An object with a numeric index signature does not claim to support every string key, while an object with a string index signature does claim to support every string key, which includes numeric keys as well.

---

As for the difference in behavior of `keyof Record<string, T>` is `string` while `keyof {[k: string]: T}` is `string | number`, the mapped type behavior was unchanged  by the pull request, so it's possible to confirm that it *is* this way.  As for *why* it's this way, that's harder to say for certain.  The closest I can find to a canonical answer for that is a [comment in microsoft/TypeScript#31013](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31013#issuecomment-484688145) by the TS dev team lead:

> As for that behavior not applying to mapped types, well, producing different behavior is why we add different syntax.
> For deeper research, start at [#23592](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/23592)

So, presumably `keyof {[P in K]: T}` being `K` is important to preserve even if `K` is `string`, and the reason it is inconsistent with `keyof {[k: string]: T}` is because the differing syntax allows to choose between the two behaviors.  I guess.  Anyway it points back to microsoft/TypeScript#23592.