# Typescript "keyof typeof" types derived from objects?

Tags: typescript, typeof, keyof

Can anyone explain the typescript "keyof typeof" behavior illustrated in the examples below and perhaps suggest a workaround:

```
// Test the behavior of the keyof operator 
// deno --version
//      deno 1.40.3 (release, x86_64-pc-windows-msvc)
//      v8 12.1.285.6
//      typescript 5.3.3

// Working example
const kRec = {
    k1: 'k1',    
    k2: 'k2',
    k3: 'k3',
    k4: 'k4',
}

// This returns: "k1" | "k2" | "k3" | "k4"
type _kRecFieldsType = keyof typeof kRec

// Same, but with a type definition
type KRecType1 = Record< string, string>

const kRec1: KRecType1 = {
    k1: 'k1',    
    k2: 'k2',
    k3: 'k3',
    k4: 'k4',
}

// This returns: string
type _kRecFieldsType1 = keyof typeof kRec1


// Same, but with another type definition
type KRecType2 = { [ key: string ]:   string }

const kRec2: KRecType2 = {
    k1: 'k1',    
    k2: 'k2',
    k3: 'k3',
    k4: 'k4',
}
// This returns: string | number
type _kRecFieldsType2 = keyof typeof kRec2
```

Running the 3 examples I expected to see the same generated type.

Comment: The first one was inferred as having those four keys, so that's the type you get when you instpect it.  You annotated the second and third types with `Record<string` and `{[key: string]` so you get those types (that's what you asked for by annotating)... and if you care about the difference between 2 and 3 then you're basically asking [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77926787/2887218).  Does that fully address the question or am I missing something?

Comment: Thanks for quick reply! I get what you are saying, so the workaround would be:

type KRecType1 = Record<keyof typeof kRec, string>

const kRec1: KRecType1 = {
    k1: 'k10',    
    k2: 'k21',
    k3: 'k32',
    k4: 'k43',
}

Comment: I'd think just `typeof kRec` is fine if all the properties are `string` anyway. I'm not sure what you're trying to "work around" though; can't you just use inference for all three?  That is, why do you need to annotate types at all?

Comment: I am working with tooling and I am not defining these objects myself, but I need the field names as generics to control what users can enter/define elsewhere, i.e. as a type-checked reference from within another object. I still think tsc should look at the 'const' declaration in front of the object and then apply the "keyof typeof" in a more consistant way, but that's just me :-)

Comment: TypeScript is behaving consistently as far as I understand it. If you write different things you get different results. Where is the inconsistency? ... so, what should we do with this question? Are you primarily asking about the difference between 1 and 2&3, or the difference between 2 and 3?  (Pleeeease don't say "both", they are different things and have different explanations)

Comment: My problem is with the "keyof" operator, that gives you a "list of keys" for an untyped const object and the "name of a type" for a type annotated object. These are as you rightly state different things and I get the logic: "keyof" is a basically type operator and the "keyof typeof" for an untyped object is a special case.